# How to view files ordered by extension in dired?

Tags: dired

Instead of viewing dired buffers with files sorted by name, I want to view it with directories at the top followed by files grouped by extension (and then filename). Is there any package to install to do that? How do I set up my config?

Answer (score 5):

You can use this:

```
(setq dired-listing-switches
      "-lX --group-directories-first")
```

The `X` option makes it sorted by extension. Basically you can just
google whatever `ls` option you want, and then set
`dired-listing-switches` accordingly.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work under Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Library [`dired-sort-menu.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/dired-sort-menu.el) lets you do this (and more): just choose `Extension` in the `Sort By` submenu of menu `Subdir`. (`Subdir` is `Dir` in [**Dired+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/DiredPlus).)

See also library [`dired-sort-menu+.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/dired-sort-menu%2b.el).

Answer (score 0):

You can set `dired-listing-switches` to `"-l --group-directories-first"`, and then toggle sorting by extension (and other keys) with:

```
(mapc (lambda (elt)
        (define-key dired-mode-map (car elt)
          `(lambda ()
            (interactive)
            (dired-sort-other (concat dired-listing-switches ,(cadr elt))))))
      '(([(control f3)]       ""     "by name")
        ([(control f4)]       " -X"  "by extension")
        ([(control f5)]       " -t"  "by date")
        ([(control f6)]       " -S"  "by size")
        ([(control shift f3)] " -r"  "by reverse name")
        ([(control shift f4)] " -rX" "by reverse extension")
        ([(control shift f5)] " -rt" "by reverse date")
        ([(control shift f6)] " -rS" "by reverse size")))
```